# SQL Query does not return NULL values after comparing the result with zero

Tags: sql-server

I am using MSSQL 2008. 
I was trying to do something like this :

```
select  Name, AcctBal 
from Table1 
where AcctBal <> '0.00'
```

Why does this query, not return the `AcctBal` with `NULL` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because NULL isn't a specific nummeric value or any other value. If you would also like to view te records that have NULL, you should change your where statement to : where AcctBal <> '0.00' or AcctBall is null

Answer (score 5):

To compare column value with `NULL` you must use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

```
select  Name, AcctBal from Table1 where AcctBal <> '0.00' OR AcctBal IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparison to null is false
need to add

```
or AcctBal is null
```

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers are correct, based on the ANSI standard, but SQL Server does provide a switch to override this (I wouldn't recommend using it, but helpful to understand the whole picture).

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON -- this is ON by default
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 <> NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Answer

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 <> NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Answer
```

In addition, it's important to realize this same behavior aopplies to NOT IN (a nasty gotcha):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON -- this is ON by default
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL NOT IN (1,2,3) THEN 'not there' ELSE 'there' END
```